# How to delete domain name in Text using preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have sample text like this:

> Nytimes.com One of the biggest news portals, have a lot of contents inside. Several search engine like www.Google.com, www.yahoo.com and yandex.ru send their crawler to this sites. This also Bing.comremoved

So I want use regex `preg_replace` to remove all domain inside. The results should be:

> One of the biggest news portals, have a lot of contents inside. Several search engine like and send their crawler to this sites. This also removed

This is my fail experiment:

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/s(.*?)\.(?:aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)/', '', $text);
```

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: The regex `/([A-Za-z0-9]+?)\.(se|com)/` does a little better atleast, the `.*?` matches way to much since domain names can't include 0 chars or special chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
/([wW]{3,3}\.|)[A-Za-z0-9]+?\.(se|com|ru)/
```

replace the last se|com|ru with what you need instead. Although after this you'll have something like this:

> One of the biggest news portals, have a lot of contents inside.
>   Several search engine like ,  and  send their crawler to this sites.
>   This also removed

To remove the space in the start you could do `trim($str)` and for the other spaces a regex that looks something like `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);` should help you.

Comment: Thanks anton, it's works! Also, great for the trim and other spaces regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$patterrn='/([wW]{3,3}\.|)[A-Za-z0-9]+?\.(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)/';
$text="Nytimes.com One of the biggest news portals, have a lot of contents inside. Several search engine like www.Google.com, www.yahoo.com and yandex.ru send their crawler to this sites. This also Bing.comremoved";
$output = preg_replace($patterrn,"",$text);
print_r($output);

?>
```

Output:

```
One of the biggest news portals, have a lot of contents inside. Several search engine like , and send their crawler to this sites. This also removed
```

Comment: I choose anton as the solution because it came first. Your answer is more detail and easy understand for people who came here. Thanks anyway!